# Parse API 1.6.4 - cannot build project

Tags: ios, parse-platform, arm64, bolts-framework

I downloaded the new iOS Parse API (1.6.4) and tried to build my project. When I do, I get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64" "_BFTaskMultipleExceptionsException", referenced from:
  ___53+[PFObject(Private) deleteAllAsync:withSessionToken:]_block_invoke214 in Parse(PFObject.o)
  ___65+[PFObject(Private) _deepSaveAsync:withCurrentUser:sessionToken:]_block_invoke311 in Parse(PFObject.o) 
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: I also get following warning: "Auto-Linking supplied '(path)/Bolts.framework/Bolts', framework linker option at (path)/Bolts.framework/Bolts is not a dylib"

Comment: You say you downloaded the new version. Was your project working with an older version?

Comment: Yes it was. Also when I remove new API and copy back old API (1.6.3), it works.

Comment: Do you have the Facebook SDK framework in the project as well?

I'm having the same problem, just to clarify

Comment: Looks like you forgot to add the Bolts.framework, can you double-check this?

Comment: I can't speak for mirap, but my problem was originally caused by bolts.framework conflicting with facebooksdk.framework. Another question on the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25840546/facebooksdk-and-bolts-conflicting-each-other-duplicate-symbols-on-build

Comment: I have Facebook SDK linked as well. But - I need Bolts framework for Local Datastore. I need to do this:
    [[query findObjectsInBackground] continueWithSuccessBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
        ......

Comment: I am having the sale problem.

Comment: Ok, issue is already reported as bug here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/383331175179417/ Please follow.

Comment: I'm using Parse 1.6.5 and Facebook SDK 3.23.2, and I'm still getting the same error. Thoughts?

Comment: Yes, the bug is still there.

Comment: For future users -"Bolts.framework". you can get it inside parse latest SDK https://www.parse.com/docs/downloads

Answer (score 12):

Temporary workaround for Parse 1.6.4 and Facebook SDK 3.23:

Add to your AppDelegate.m or another class following constant after imports and before implementation section:

```
NSString *const BFTaskMultipleExceptionsException = @"BFMultipleExceptionsException";

@interface IPAppDelegate ()
@end

@implementation IPAppDelegate
```

It should solve the problem until it'll be solved on Parse/Facebook side.

--
Update: This solution is only for Facebook and Parse SDK versions that listed above and these versions right now are outdated.

New Parse SDK 1.7.4 works correct with new Facebook SDK 4.0 and there shouldn't be such a problem.

Comment: This makes error with 1 duplicate (and that's the one in AppDelegate).

Comment: Did you check frameworks versions? Did you installed additional Bolts framework or which comes not with Facebook SDK?

Comment: I installed latest Bolts, not the one that comes in FacebookSDK. But - it seems that there's Bolts built directly in FacebookSDK.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, but the one which comes with Facebook SDK doesn't contain symbols which are already in the SDK. Could you try with it?

Comment: Surkov Yes, that seems to be the problem.

Comment: There wouldn't be, because linker won't find it. The best solution would be to create an empty objective c file and the constant to it You need to make sure that your file is added to compile sources.

Comment: This solution can take away the error but there're some side-effects. With this implemented in my app, I found this in my log when logging into the app: **-[BFTask isFaulted]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x18b00da0** and my app just goes freezed but no crashed. Is anyone know how to deal with this?

Comment: I'm having the same problem @SanitLee. Was anyone able to solve this issue?

Comment: @c0d3Junk13 I'm not sure if your case is the same as mine but I kinda managed to overcome this by just upgrading new Parse framework following this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29509641/apple-mach-o-linker-error-when-architectures-to-support-64-bit-added  Have you tried that yet?

Comment: Thanks, so I should take out that line from the AppDelegate. However when I do this I'm running into different issues I believe due to my misconfiguration of the project... Here is one of the issues I'm having if you could help, I'd be very thankful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30925687/parse-loginwithusernameinbackground-block-callback-not-working

Answer (score 5):

I was able to figure out the URL for anyone that needs Parse iOS v1.6.3.

https://parse.com/downloads/ios/parse-library/1.6.3

I can confirm that everything compiles properly using 1.6.3.

Comment: This answer is the only that helped me. Was no -ObjC flags etc. Bolts 1.1.4 doesn't fix anything. Thank you!

Comment: I was looking forward to 1.6.4 because of performance improvements with Local Datastore, so I have to wait anyway.

Comment: Anys url to download 1.6.3 ? It seems this url is for the latest version ?

Comment: This URL used to work, but today it'll download 1.6.4 no matter what. This is unfortunate because as we all know it's not possible to compile with 1.6.4

Comment: Looks like it links back to 1.6.3.

Answer (score 3):

Placing

```
NSString *const BFTaskMultipleExceptionsException = @"BFMultipleExceptionsException";
```

in the App Delegate as suggested by Sergey Surkov in between the imports and the implementation and then adding libstdc++.6.dylib in build phases worked for me. Please also view https://stackoverflow.com/a/27628797/1036945

Answer (score 3):

I've had the exact same problem using the latest SDKs from Parse (1.7.4) and Facebook (4.2.0). The problem is caused by the Bolts.framework included in both Parse and Facebook SDKs. For some reason the Bolts framework in Parse is always newer than the one included in the Facebook SDK.

After many-many attempts at installing, removing and re-installing these SDKs, using the drag and drop method and via Cocoapods, I finally managed to overcome this issue by undertaking the following steps:

1. I removed completely any instance of the Parse, Facebook and Bolts frameworks from my project;
2. I re-added the FBSDKCoreKit framework (and the ShareKit and LoginKit for the needs of my project) following the steps on the Facebook developer page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/
   Make sure NOT to copy the items to your project.
3. I re-added the Parse framework to the project using the drag-and-drop method. I also added the ParseFacebookUtilsV4 framework because I needed it to create users via Facebook Login.
4. This was the most important step that solved everything: I added the Bolts.framework provided by Parse by dragging it to the project, but making sure NOT to copy it to the project (just like with the FBSDKCoreKit framework, I deselected the "Copy items into destination group's folder." option. If you copy it to the project folder, the project won't build.

These steps finally solved all my problems.

Comment: Yep... Step 4 certainly was important! Spent hours on this.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using cocoapods try `pod update Bolts`

Answer (score 1):

EDIT2: FacebookSDK Update 3.23.2 resolves this issue and includes Bolts 1.1.4: https://developers.facebook.com/resources/facebook-ios-sdk-3.23.2.pkg

---

EDIT:
Drop -ObjC "Other Linker Flag" from your Build settings.

---

Bolts.framework is not necessary with Parse if Facebook SDK is integrated.

As of Facebook iOS SDK 3.14 bolts.framework is included. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/upgrading-3.x 

Try removing your manual instance of bolts.framework.

Comment: If I remove Bolts framework, these errors are out. But - I get different errors because of missing Bolts framework while I have Parse Local Datastore implemented. (......  [[query findObjectsInBackground] continueWithSuccessBlock:^id(BFTask *task) { ......)

NOTE: I have FacebookSDK linked in the project (and in header of this class as well).

Comment: Ok figured it out. Drop -ObjC "Other Linker Flag" from your Build settings. This might be an issue if you use CocoaPods, otherwise it is working now on my end.

Comment: Ok, but I need -ObjC for GoogleMaps SDK.

Comment: Can you please explain how to Drop -ObjC "Other Linker Flag"? I am also in the same boat as all of you integrating Parse with Facebook SDK. I have removed the Bolts.framework and now have the same issue stated above. I am using Objectice-C, not Swift.

Comment: @jdmorgenstein If you don't know how to drop it, you're probably building without -ObjC flag. :) Which is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Just to put the record straight.

The issue is caused because of a conflict with the Bolts framework between the Facebook SDK Bolts and the Parse bolts framework. A temporary solution to get around this issue is to use Cocoapods for your Facebook SDK dependency which will help while a fix is worked on.

The bug has been acknowledged by Facebook & is being assigned to the appropriate team for fixing.

Please follow https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/383331175179417/ for the updates.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the facebook sdk framework and bolts framework (comes with fb sdk) is imported into your project.

Answer (score 0):

i got similar error ("...is not a dylib" and "Undefined symbols for architecture") because i dragged the whole parse folder ("parse-library-1.7.4-2") into my xcode project, when i should have dragged only the frameworks i needed ("Bolts.framework" and "Parse.framework").  deleted the parse folder, dragged over the two frameworks, then everything works as expected :)

Answer (score -1):

I had the exact same problem. Updating Bolts to 1.1.4 solved it for me (Bolts was 1.1.3 before).

If you use cocoapods, change or add this line to your podfile

```
pod 'Bolts', '1.1.4'
```

If not, just download it here : https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-iOS/releases

Comment: This works, but it makes conflict with FacebookSDK which has Bolts included. But - I cannot remove Bolts from my project (and - I cannot link to Bolts used in FacebookSDK). RESULT: I get 91 duplicates.

Comment: @mirap I also have Facebook SDK. I have it via cocoapods. I have no problem updating Bolts without updating Facebook SDK. This is my podfile config :
pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK', '3.23.0'
pod 'Bolts', '1.1.4'

Answer (score -1):

Try downloading the latest SDK and replacing all of the Parse frameworks with the latest version.